# Facing issue while running the spark scala unit test program in intellij, it is not even instantiating the tests and same for all the test programs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

```bash
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.ScalaBuildProcessParametersProvider.addOpens(ScalaBuildProcessParametersProvider.scala:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.ScalaBuildProcessParametersProvider.getVMArguments(ScalaBuildProcessParametersProvider.scala:23)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.launchBuildProcess(BuildManager.java:1414)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.lambda$scheduleBuild$14(BuildManager.java:971)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:216)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:27)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:195)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:213)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:184)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Just with that stacktrace is hard to guess what could be the problem. Try to add more details. Maybe some code, how the project is built, what command you executed to get that error